# Unable to get 3200Mhz from 3200Mhz RAM on Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I am using Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro Wifi motherbard, AMD Ryzen 7 2600x, Corsair DDR4 2x8GB 3200Mhz RAM (CMK16GX4M2B3200C16). My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

I plugged in the 2 RAM sticks onto RAM slots #1 and #2 as advised in the motherboard manual. On the Bios, I chose XMP profile. After I boot up the PC, I still get 2133Mhz RAM clock instead of 3200Mhz RAM. 3200Mhz RAM is required to unleash the performance of Ryzen 7 2700x due to the Infinity Fabric design.

I do not know what else I miss out to achieve 3200Mhz RAM. Can the experts here help?

Thank you.

Comment: XMP is an Intel extension of JEDEC SPD standard.  It is not guaranteed to be supported by AMD hardware (actually shocked an AMD motherboard is supporting it).  Any event Ryzen is known to be very sensitive with regards to memory compatibility.  I suspect you have simply run into a compatibility issue with Ryzen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The problem has been fixed.

The cause of the culprit is totally unexpected. It is not a hardware problem and has nothing to do with the motherboard.

After I **uninstall Avast anti-virus** and switch to using native Windows 10 Defender anti-virus software, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you use gigabyte easytune software also and set the memory frequency there as well to 32 and the bios will retain the settings.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This reads like an ad for easytune.  What is it, where do you get it, and why use that rather than anything else?

Comment: Gigabyte EasTune is a freeware  simple and easy-to-use interface from Gigabyte that allows users to fine tune their system settings or adjust system and memory clocks and voltages in a Windows environment.

Answer (score -1):

Update your bios to version 5 and it should solve it as I had version 2 bios and games crashed and so did Windows 10